# Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'

testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.2.1"
// Required -- JUnit 4 framework
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
// Optional -- Mockito framework
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

### }

It shows me error saying "Execution failed for task ':Application:javaPreCompileDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':Application:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath'.
> Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.1.0/support-annotations-25.1.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.1.0/support-annotations-25.1.0.pom
> - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.1.0/support-annotations-25.1.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :Application > com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1 > com.jakewharton:butterknife-annotations:8.5.1"

Comment: Did you apply plugin and other ?
classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.2.3'
and 
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

Comment: i am really new to android developing so i have no clue sorry

Comment: Read here carefully how to add butterknife: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife